# Run stored procedure: user type not defined error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run the following Stored Procedure on the click of the OK Button:

```
Private Sub ok_Click()

Dim objConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objCom As ADODB.Command
Dim provStr As String

Set objCom = New ADODB.Command

objConnection.Provider = "sqloledb"
provStr = "Data Source=Server Name;" & "Initial Catalog=DB NAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=Password;"

objConnection.Open provStr

With objCom
    .ActiveConnection = objConnection
    .CommandText = "dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match 74"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

The error is:User type not defined. The stored procedure runs correctly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: In addition to [Remou](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11420192/190829)'s answer, I would not use `Dim ... As New` as this will create auto-instancing variables.

Comment: In the future, indicate which line triggers the error.  I'm confident Remou guessed correctly.  But my point is do not make us guess ... just tell us.

Comment: It's not exactly a guess @HansUp, but I agree otherwise with your point :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your references, in particular ensure you are referencing the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library.